# SQL How to Select Everything Where One of Several Conditions Exist

Tags: sql, if-statement, case, conditional-statements, where-clause

First off thanks for the help!  My question is this... How can I create a SQL SELECT statement that selects everything WHERE certain conditions/cases exist.  See example below:

I would like the SQL statement to SELECT everything within the given table WHERE the *$userID (a PHP variable with type INT)* meets any of the 4 conditions/cases.

Each of the 4 conditions: *type1_id*, *type2_id*, *type3_id*, and *type4_id* are all columns within the same table.

*That being said feel free to describe how this could also be done if each of the types were housed within separate tables.*

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE 
    if(type1_id > 0) 
    {
        type1_id = '$userID' 
    }
    elseif (type2_id > 0)
    {
        type2_id = '$userID'
    }
    elseif (type3_id > 0)
    {
        type3_id = '$userID'
    }
    elseif (type4_id > 0)
    {
        type4_id = '$userID'
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
WHERE (type1_id > 0 AND type1_id = '$user_id')
OR    (type2_id > 0 AND type2_id = '$user_id')
OR    (type3_id > 0 AND type3_id ...
```

It would be helpful to see a selection of your table data, but this will ensure that both conditions are met, yet still allow you to check multiple 'sets' of conditions.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use IN.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE '$UserID' IN (type1_id,type2_id,type3_id,type4_id)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks so much for the help. One quick question, is this the most efficient way to accomplish this particular SELECT statement? It appears as if it is just based on its simplicity. Would the only draw back be that with this method you can't check if the various type_id's are greater then 0?

Comment: You could still check that an id is greater than 0. Just add an AND '$UserID' > 0 in the WHERE statement. It will still evaluate how you desire, it just does it in reverse basing everything on your variable.

Answer (score 1):

In general, use the `OR` statement.

```
WHERE < one boolean statement > 
OR    < another boolean statement >
```

Specifically for what you want, because the inside of each OR will look the same you can use a CASE statement, like this:

```
where '$userID' = case when type1_id > 0 then type1_id
                       when type2_id > 0 then type2_id
                       ... 
                   end
```

Of course if you don't need to check the `typeX_id > 0` then as @Apothosis suggests, using `IN` is by far the best approach!

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from tablename
where type1_id > 0 and type1_id = '$userID' 
   or type2_id > 0 and type2_id = '$userID' 
   or type3_id > 0 and type3_id = '$userID' 
   or type4_id > 0 and type4_id = '$userID'
```

is the elseif really necessary or can always only one typeN_id be >0 ?

if the elseif is important:

```
select *
from tablename
where type1_id > 0 and type1_id = '$userID' 
   or type1_id <=0 and type2_id > 0 and type2_id = '$userID' 
   or type1_id <= 0 and type2_id <= 0 and type3_id > 0 and type3_id = '$userID' 
   or type1_id <= 0 and type2_id <= 0 and type3_id <= 0 and type4_id > 0 and type4_id = '$userID'
```

What should happen if a record as a 0 value for all typeN_id columns ? In your logic it will be in the result.

Comment: I believe that for my purposes the first option works the best! Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions shortly, but first, the most literal and direct answer to your question:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE 
  (type1_id > 0 and type1_id = '$userID')
OR
  (type2_id > 0 and type2_id = '$userID')
OR
  (type3_id > 0 and type3_id = '$userID')
OR
  (type4_id > 0 and type4_id = '$userID')
```

Now, a few concerns:

1. Concatenating $userID directly into the SQL has a couple of risks:

   - SQL injection
   - Reparsing the query every time
2. Comparing each column numerically as `>0` and then equal to a string feels fishy.  What data type is this?  I wonder if the `> 0` is redundant.  If they are not really needed, it may make your query easier to maintain and have a more reliable execution plan if you can avoid the nested AND/OR combinations.  But only if they are in fact redundant.
3. Implicit type conversion / casting by comparing an integer to the string representation of that number.  This will cause extra CPU cycles and may prevent index seeks.

Comment: This worked great!  I definitely understand your concerns regarding the PHP variable in the SQL statement but I'm taking precautions by validating the datatype, as well as sanitizing it... so I should be good as far as the SQL injection concerns go.

Comment: With regards to #2 I'm using a data type of INT... Is there a more efficient way of accomplishing my request without multiple nested OR statements?

Comment: It depends on whether `$userID` can ever be <= 0.  If it cannot be, then checking if it equals the column is sufficient.  It's like asking "is x equal to 5 and greater than 0?"  If it's equal to 5, you know it's greater than 0.  If `$userID` can never be <= 0, then remove the > 0 checks and just `OR` the equality checks like this: `WHERE type1_id = $userID OR type2_id = $userID OR type3_id = $userID OR $type4_id = $userID`.

Comment: Since the type columns are integers, I suggest removing the quotes around the variables.  The quotes are going to cause an implicit cast, which is extra work for the DB server and may block index usage (if there are any viable indexes on those columns).  Updating my answer to specify this.